# Issues using pure CSS parallax and calculating viewport

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm trying to use Keith Clarks pure CSS parallax on the following page:

http://www.applaus-potsdam.de/dev/

This works so far:

http://www.applaus-potsdam.de/dev3/

But apparently the parallex effect enables the browser to calculate to which point the user has scrollt so far – if you have an eye on the navigation bar. Neither the nav is fixed on the top of the screen nor the logo appears, nor the navigation links work at all.

```
$( document ).scrollTop();
```

So the value in this part allways stays 0.

Is there any solution or a work around for this issue?

Using a parallax effect with js didn't work for me so far since most of the plug-ins I found are dealing with changing just the scrolling speed of a background image.

Another issue I noticed is that the effects works well in Chrome and Firefox but not at all in Safari?

Would appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I see you edited scrollit.js at line 43; you changed $('html,body') to $('html,.parallax'). But you can better just change it to $('.parallax') only as we don't animate the main document

And the solution to your current problem is to replace line 42 by:

```
var targetTop = $('[data-scroll-index=' + ndx + ']').offset().top + settings.topOffset.val + 1 + $('.parallax').scrollTop();
```

So at the end, you add the scrollposition inside .parallax ($('.parallax').scrollTop()) to compensate for the scrolling offset

Don't forget also that you can position your bottom menu fixed to the screen bottom using css position:fixed

---

The reason that document.scrollTop() returns zero is because the scrolling doesn't happen in the document body, but in the .parallax container (the scrollbars are in that container). The body doesn't have any vertical overflow (the parallax div is 100% height (100vh)) and therefore no scrolling can happen in the body. But your js plugin for smooth scrolling upon click (scrollit.js) tries to scroll to body, this is why it won't work together with your parallax div.

See in the scrollit.js docs if it's possible to specify an alternative container instead of the body when you initialize the script. Else, try if it works to apply the css rules that you have for .parallax, on the body (and change html structure accordingly)

The elements that should have a fixed position ('nav ul' for instance) should then have position: fixed instead of position: absolute

good luck

Comment: I tried to change the scrollit.js to the the .parallax container. It works, but for sure not properly: I can use the navigation now as long as I am on top of the page. If I am not, the anchors are apparently calculated in a wrong way. But yeah, I don't really get it why does?

Comment: I guess (guess because i never used it) the scrollit js calculates the position of the anchors wrong; compared to the body instead of to the .parallax container or the other way around, and therefore scrolls either too far or not far enough if you are not at the top. But please provide an example of what you have now.

Comment: Maybe else try the other option that I mentioned: to use the body as the parallax parent container instead of the .parallax div.

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot the current link: http://www.applaus-potsdam.de/dev6/

yeah, already tried the second option and the effect was that the effect just didn't work at all anymore

Comment: Great, navigation works now indeed.
But positioning fixed doesn't work: apparently the nav has to be within the .parallax container – if it is, the nav works, but stays absolute and scrolls. If I place it outside that container the nav is fixed, but doens't work anymore. Frustrating. Do you see a solution or what's the issue? Thanks for your help. If this could be fixed I woulhd be happy.
Still the current state is http://www.applaus-potsdam.de/dev6/

Comment: on line 123 you changed $('body') to $('.parallax'), this causes your current problem. Change it back to $('body') and it will work.

To explain: that line selects elements within the specified container, and searches links with attributes [data-scroll-nav] or [data-scroll-goto], and then 'listens' to their click events. Upon click, it will prevent the default behavior (which is to open the link in the 'href' attribute) Instead, it will execute the ScrollIt behavior.

SEE NEXT COMMENT - I REACHED MAXIMUM CHARACTER COUNT

Comment: By changing 'body' to '.parallax' you made the script only search for there elements in the .parallax container. But, as the menu is now outside the parallax container, so it can't find the links in there. Changing it to body will make jQuery search in the entire document

Comment: Great! Thanks, also for the explanation.
One last thing: Both things don't work in safari, neither parallax nor the navigation. I tried it with with fixing it by including the webkit- comand on perspective but no effect.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot test on safari here but I am pretty sure the parallax thing is indeed because of a missing -webkit- somewhere, not only on 'perspective', also check transform, transform-origin etc. See http://shouldiprefix.com/
Also it depends wether you are looking in Safari on Apple or on Windows. The Windows Safari is known to be bugged and support of it has ended, so don't trust Windows Safari.
Als check the javascript console for possible errors